# Vim throwing a "Not an editor command: JSHint" error

Tags: vim, jshint

I have JSHint installed and working in vim as evidenced by the fact that when I save a file, I can see it pointing out the errors in the code.

But when I type in :JSHint at the command line, it says it's not a command.

I'm using the pathogen.vim plugin but it didn't work before I installed pathogen, either.

Comment: Is that a JSHint plugin? The JSHint program? How do you perform the verification? What other plugins do you have? Be more specific.

Comment: See below. I figured out the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think the issue is that I downloaded a flavor of JSHint for vim that does not have the JSHint command.

This is what I downloaded: https://github.com/vim-scripts/jshint.vim--Stelmach

I was reading the documentation at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3576